# Adding a new block in a theme in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to add a new .phtml file inside a current container. I've tracked down the container and using the Magento_Catalog/layout/product_view.xml layout file I can add a new .phtml file. However, I'm wondering if this is possible without using the Magento_Catalog namespace?

My theme is at MyTheme/Theme and all I want to do is insert a .phtml file below the default Add To Cart button.

Comment: check this  http://www.onlinecode.org/call-phtml-file-cms-page-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

You should add that path into your theme and include the addition there. So;
`MyTheme/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/product_view.xml`

This is the conventional way to do this in magento2